# Pug prints the same value multiple times

Tags: javascript, node.js, pug

Here is my pug code:

```
html
  head
    style
        include ../../public/css/admin/admin.css
  body
    .main
      .yeniler-kutu
        each yeni, index in yeniler
          li(class="yeniler")= yeni 
    script
      include ../../public/js/admin/admin.js
```

Here is my backend javascript code:

```
router.get("/index", async (req, res) =>
{
    try
    {
            const users = await User.find({});
            for(x=0; users[x]; x++)
            {
                if(users[x].gorev === "Menti" && !users[x].mentor)
                {
                    yenilerArr.push(users[x].name);
                }
            }
            res.status(200).send(pug.renderFile("./views/admin/admin.pug", 
            {
                yeniler: yenilerArr,
            })) 
    }
    catch(e)
    {
        res.status(400).send(e)
    }
})
```

The problem is pug is displaying the same list element multiple times. When I first load the page It works fine and only displays the strings once but when I reload the page I see the duplicate values.
For example if `yeniler` array contains only one element called `hello`, it displays the string `hello` but when I reload the page I see 2 `hello`s. Thanks for reading.

Comment: The only thing that can persist page refresh(even hard) is caching/states or db. Make sure that you dont modify db(f.e. model push) and that your view doesn't use any kind of browser storage (local, etc)

Comment: Thanks. I was using push.

Answer (score 0):

I think little semantically mistake here:

```
for(x=0; users[x]; x++)
```

should be:

```
for(x=0; users.length; x++)
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like `yenilerArr` is defined outside the scope of the request handler, therefore it persists between requests, and acts like a global variable.

It should be defined inside request handler, somewhere before `for` loop:

```
const yenilerArr = []
```